# Minecraft Forge Cancel Event / Do Not Notify Server

Tags: java, events, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I have an EntityInteract Event

```
@SubscribeEvent(priority = EventPriority.HIGHEST)
public static void EntityInteractEvent(PlayerInteractEvent.EntityInteract event) {
    if (event.getPlayer() != null && event.getWorld() != null && event.getTarget() instanceof AbstractHorseEntity) {
        PlayerEntity player = event.getPlayer();
        AbstractHorseEntity horseEntity = (AbstractHorseEntity) event.getTarget();
        if (player.isCrouching()) {
            Item main = player.getHeldItemMainhand().getItem();
            for (Item a : allowed) {
                if (main.equals(a)) {
                    String[] result = new HorseStats().getHorseStats(horseEntity);
                    for (String s : result) {
                        if (s != null && !s.isEmpty())
                            player.sendMessage(new TranslationTextComponent(s));
                    }
                    event.setCancellationResult(ActionResultType.SUCCESS);
                    event.setResult(Event.Result.DENY);
                    event.setCanceled(true);

                    return;
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

It is not cancelled when I click a horse with an allowed item. Thus the Server still recieves the click and the inventory of the Horse is opened.

How can i prevent this?

The event is correctly fired and processed, the ChatMessages are being printed to the Client.

Comment: Have you tried adding a `!world.IsRemote()` check so the code would run only on servers? Maybe the client is receiving it and doing strange things to the event - as a rule, do logic checks on servers only.